# JQuery Change Drop Down List Items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a fairly complicated piece of code that a previous programmer wrote for me; however, it is now showing an error in the console and blocking other jquery scripts from running on the page. I wouldn't really care about the console error, but it is blocking a modal box from popping up for users to login along with blocking fancybox lightbox.

To see a live version of the problem you could go to: http://www.cabcot.com/listings/united-states/colorado/alamosa/.

The goal of the code is to have a drop down list automatically get filled based upon a previously selected drop down list. For example, using the previously mentioned url in the top left "Search Listings" if someone selects "United States" it would then have a list of states in that country. Then if the user selects a state in would display a list of cities in that state in the select box below. That part works well, except for it continually throws the console code "Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined" and is blocking other jquery modal boxes and lightboxes. I believe I have narrowed down the problem to an on-page javascript that automatically fills in the dropdown selects if that person is on a specific page. For example if the user is on the page for Colorado, then the select box for Country would be United States, for State would be Colorado. All of it does what it is supposed to do, but it blocks other jquery scripts from running. Here is the code:

**Javascript Ajax**

```
 <?php
  header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
  // ...
?>


function sack(file) {
this.xmlhttp = null;
this.resetData = function () {
    this.method = "POST";
    this.queryStringSeparator = "?";
    this.argumentSeparator = "&";
    this.URLString = "";
    this.encodeURIString = true;
    this.execute = false;
    this.element = null;
    this.elementObj = null;
    this.requestFile = file;
    this.vars = new Object();
    this.responseStatus = new Array(2);
};
this.resetFunctions = function () {
    this.onLoading = function () {};
    this.onLoaded = function () {};
    this.onInteractive = function () {};
    this.onCompletion = function () {};
    this.onError = function () {};
    this.onFail = function () {};
};
this.reset = function () {
    this.resetFunctions();
    this.resetData();
};
this.createAJAX = function () {
    try {
        this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e1) {
        try {
            this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e2) {
            this.xmlhttp = null;
        }
    }
    if (!this.xmlhttp) {
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
            this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            this.failed = true;
        }
    }
};
this.setVar = function (name, value) {
    this.vars[name] = Array(value, false);
};
this.encVar = function (name, value, returnvars) {
    if (true == returnvars) {
        return Array(encodeURIComponent(name), encodeURIComponent(value));
    } else {
        this.vars[encodeURIComponent(name)] =     Array(encodeURIComponent(value), true);
    }
}
this.processURLString = function (string, encode) {
    encoded = encodeURIComponent(this.argumentSeparator);
    regexp = new RegExp(this.argumentSeparator + "|" + encoded);
    varArray = string.split(regexp);
    for (i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
        urlVars = varArray[i].split("=");
        if (true == encode) {
            this.encVar(urlVars[0], urlVars[1]);
        } else {
            this.setVar(urlVars[0], urlVars[1]);
        }
    }
}
this.createURLString = function (urlstring) {
    if (this.encodeURIString && this.URLString.length) {
        this.processURLString(this.URLString, true);
    }
    if (urlstring) {
        if (this.URLString.length) {
            this.URLString += this.argumentSeparator + urlstring;
        } else {
            this.URLString = urlstring;
        }
    }
    this.setVar("rndval", new Date().getTime());
    urlstringtemp = new Array();
    for (key in this.vars) {
        if (false == this.vars[key][1] && true == this.encodeURIString) {
            encoded = this.encVar(key, this.vars[key][0], true);
            delete this.vars[key];
            this.vars[encoded[0]] = Array(encoded[1], true);
            key = encoded[0];
        }
        urlstringtemp[urlstringtemp.length] = key + "=" + this.vars[key][0];
    }
    if (urlstring) {
        this.URLString += this.argumentSeparator + urlstringtemp.join(this.argumentSeparator);
    } else {
        this.URLString += urlstringtemp.join(this.argumentSeparator);
    }
}
this.runResponse = function () {
    eval(this.response);
}
this.runAJAX = function (urlstring) {
    if (this.failed) {
        this.onFail();
    } else {
        this.createURLString(urlstring);
        if (this.element) {
            this.elementObj = document.getElementById(this.element);
        }
        if (this.xmlhttp) {
            var self = this;
            if (this.method == "GET") {
                totalurlstring = this.requestFile + this.queryStringSeparator + this.URLString;
                this.xmlhttp.open(this.method, totalurlstring, true);
            } else {
                this.xmlhttp.open(this.method, this.requestFile, true);
                try {
                    this.xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                } catch (e) {}
            }
            this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                switch (self.xmlhttp.readyState) {
                    case 1:
                        self.onLoading();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        self.onLoaded();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        self.onInteractive();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        self.response = self.xmlhttp.responseText;
                        self.responseXML = self.xmlhttp.responseXML;
                        self.responseStatus[0] = self.xmlhttp.status;
                        self.responseStatus[1] = self.xmlhttp.statusText;
                        if (self.execute) {
                            self.runResponse();
                        }
                        if (self.elementObj) {
                            elemNodeName = self.elementObj.nodeName;
                            elemNodeName.toLowerCase();
                            if (elemNodeName == "input" || elemNodeName == "select" || elemNodeName == "option" || elemNodeName == "textarea") {
                                self.elementObj.value = self.response;
                            } else {
                                self.elementObj.innerHTML = self.response;
                            }
                        }
                        if (self.responseStatus[0] == "200") {
                            self.onCompletion();
                        } else {
                            self.onError();
                        }
                        self.URLString = "";
                        break;
                }
            };
            this.xmlhttp.send(this.URLString);
        }
    }
};
this.reset();
this.createAJAX();
}
var ajax = new Array();

function getFSREPlist(sel, elementidupdate, fsrepvariable, currentvalue) {
if (sel == '[object]' || sel == '[object HTMLSelectElement]') {
    var FSREPID = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
} else {
    var FSREPID = sel;
}
document.getElementById(elementidupdate).options.length = 0;
var index = ajax.length;
ajax[index] = new sack();
ajax[index].requestFile = 'http://www.cabcot.com/wp-content/plugins/firestorm-real-estate-plugin/search.php?' + fsrepvariable + '=' + FSREPID + '&cvalue=' + currentvalue;
ajax[index].onCompletion = function () {
    ElementUpdate(index, elementidupdate)
};
ajax[index].runAJAX();
}

function ElementUpdate(index, elementidupdate) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(elementidupdate);
    eval(ajax[index].response);
}
```

**Here is the search.php**

```
<?php
require("../../../wp-config.php"); 

if(isset($_GET['ProvinceID'])){
    $FSREPCities = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_cities WHERE province_id = ".$_GET['ProvinceID']." ORDER BY city_name");
    $FSREPProvince = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_provinces WHERE province_id = ".$_GET['ProvinceID']);
    $HTTPREFERER = explode('?', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if (substr($HTTPREFERER[0], -13) == '/add-listing/') {
        echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Select a City','');\n";
    } else {
        echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Search All of ".$FSREPProvince->province_name."','');\n";
    }
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($FSREPCities as $FSREPCities) {
        echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('".$FSREPCities->city_name."','".$FSREPCities->city_id."');\n";
        if ($FSREPCities->city_id == $_GET['cvalue']) {
            echo "obj.options[$count].selected = true;";
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['CountryID'])){
    $FSREPProvinces = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_provinces WHERE country_id = ".$_GET['CountryID']." ORDER BY province_name");
    $FSREPCountry = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_countries WHERE country_id = ".$_GET['CountryID']);
    $count = 1;
    echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Select a State/Province','');\n";
    foreach ($FSREPProvinces as $FSREPProvinces) {
        echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('".$FSREPProvinces->province_name."','".$FSREPProvinces->province_id."');\n";
        if ($FSREPProvinces->province_id == $_GET['cvalue']) {
            echo "obj.options[$count].selected = true;";
        }
        $count++;
    }
}


?>
```

**Here is the on-page javascript which is where the console says the error is coming from:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
            if (isset($_POST['fsrep-search-country']) && isset($_POST['fsrep-search-province'])) {
                echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function ($){getFSREPlist(\''.$_POST['fsrep-search-country'].'\', \'fsrep-search-province\', \'CountryID\', \''.$_POST['fsrep-search-province'].'\'); getFSREPlist(\''.$_POST['fsrep-search-province'].'\', \'fsrep-search-city\', \'ProvinceID\', \''.$_POST['fsrep-search-city'].'\'); request.send(null); });';
            }else {
                if ($CountryID != 0) {
                    $GetCountry = $CountryID;
                    if ($ProvinceID != 0) {
                        $GetProvince = $ProvinceID;
                    }
                    if ($CityID != 0) {
                        $GetCity = $CityID;
                    }

                    echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function ($){getFSREPlist(\''.$GetCountry.'\', \'fsrep-search-province\', \'CountryID\', \''.$GetProvince.'\'); getFSREPlist(\''.$GetProvince.'\', \'fsrep-search-city\', \'ProvinceID\', \''.$GetCity.'\'); request.send(null); });';
                }
            }   
            ?>
    </script>
```

**And finally the search widget:**

```
<?php  
function fsrep_search_widget_init() {
    if ( !function_exists('register_sidebar_widget') || !function_exists('register_widget_control') ) {
        return;
    }
    function fsrep_search_widget($args) {
        global $wpdb,$FSREPconfig,$CityID,$ProvinceID,$CountryID;
        extract($args);
        $options = get_option('fsrep_search_widget');
        $fsrep_title = empty($options['title']) ? 'Search Listings' : $options['title'];
        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title;
        echo $fsrep_title;
        echo $after_title;
        echo '<form id="fsrep_search_widget_form" name="fsrep_search_widget_form" action="'.get_option('home').'/listings/search/" method="post">';
        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">Country:</div>';
        echo '<select id="fsrep-search-country" name="fsrep-search-country"  onchange="getFSREPlist(this, \'fsrep-search-province\', \'CountryID\', \'\')">';
        echo '<option value="">Select Country</option>';
        $FSREPCountries = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_countries ORDER BY country_name");
        foreach ($FSREPCountries as $FSREPCountries) {
            if ($wpdb->get_var("SELECT listing_address_country FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings WHERE listing_address_country = ".$FSREPCountries->country_id) > 0) {
                $selected = '';
                if (isset($_POST['fsrep-search-country']) || $CountryID != 0) { 
                    if ($_POST['fsrep-search-country'] == $FSREPCountries->country_id) { 
                        $selected = ' selected'; 
                    }elseif ($CountryID == $FSREPCountries->country_id) { 
                        $selected = ' selected'; 
                    }
                }
                echo '<option value="'.$FSREPCountries->country_id.'"'.$selected.'>'.$FSREPCountries->country_name.'</option>';
            }
        }
        echo '</select></div>';
        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">State/Prov.:</div>';
        echo '<select id="fsrep-search-province" name="fsrep-search-province"  onchange="getFSREPlist(this, \'fsrep-search-city\', \'ProvinceID\', \'\')">';
        echo '<option value="">- - - - - -</option>';
        echo '</select></div>';
        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">City:</div>';
        echo '<select id="fsrep-search-city" name="fsrep-search-city">';
        echo '<option value="">- - - - - -</option>';
        echo '</select></div>';
        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">Price:</div>';
        echo '<select name="fsrep-search-price-range">';
        echo fsrep_price_range_print('options',$_POST['fsrep-search-price-range']);
        echo '</select></div>';
        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">to</div>';
        echo '<select name="fsrep-search-price-range2">';
        echo fsrep_price_range_print('options',$_POST['fsrep-search-price-range2']);
        echo '</select></div>';
        $SFields = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_fields WHERE field_search = 1 ORDER BY field_order");
        foreach($SFields as $SFields) {
            $SFieldsValue = '';
            echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title fsrepwst-'.$SFields->field_id.'">'.$SFields->field_name.'</div>';
            if ($SFields->field_type == 'selectbox') {
                echo '<select name="field-'.$SFields->field_id.'">';
                echo '<option value="">All</option>';
                $Array = explode(',',$SFields->field_value);
                for($i=0;$i<count($Array);$i++) {
                    $selected = '';
                    if (isset($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id])) { if ($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id] == $Array[$i]) { $selected = ' selected'; } }
                    echo '<option value="'.$Array[$i].'"'.$selected.'>'.$Array[$i].'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select></div>';
            } elseif ($SFields->field_type == 'radio') {
                $selected = ''; if (!isset($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id])) { $selected = ' checked'; }
                echo '<br /><label for="wsall"><input type="radio" style="width: 10px;" name="field-'.$SFields->field_id.'" value="" id="wsall"'.$selected.'> All</label>';
                $Array = explode(',',$SFields->field_value);
                for($i=0;$i<count($Array);$i++) {
                    $selected = '';
                    if (isset($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id])) { if ($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id] == $Array[$i]) { $selected = ' checked'; } }
                    echo '<label for="'.$Array[$i].'"><input type="radio" style="width: 10px;" name="field-'.$SFields->field_id.'" value="'.$Array[$i].'" id="'.$Array[$i].'" '.$selected.'> '.$Array[$i].'</label>';
                }
                echo '</select></div>';
            } elseif ($SFields->field_type == 'checkbox') {
                $selected = ''; if (!isset($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id])) { $selected = ' checked'; }
                echo '<br /><input type="checkbox" style="width: 25px;" name="field-'.$SFields->field_id.'" value="" '.$selected.' /> All &nbsp; &nbsp;<br />';
                $Array = explode(',',$SFields->field_value);
                for($i=0;$i<count($Array);$i++) {
                    $selected = '';
                    if (isset($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id])) { if ($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id] == $Array[$i]) { $selected = ' checked'; } }
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" style="width: 25px;" name="field-'.$SFields->field_id.'-'.$i.'" value="'.$Array[$i].'" '.$selected.' /> '.$Array[$i].' &nbsp; &nbsp;<br />';
                }
                echo '</select></div>';
            } else {
                if (isset($_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id])) { $SFieldsValue = $_POST['field-'.$SFields->field_id]; }
                echo '<input type="text" name="field-'.$SFields->field_id.'" id="field-'.$SFields->field_id.'" value="'.$SFieldsValue.'" />';
            }
        }


        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">Bedrooms:</div>';
        echo '<select name="fsrep-search-bedrooms">';
        echo '<option value="">All</option>';
                $Array = explode(',',$SFields->field_value);
                for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
                    $selectedbed = '';
                    if (isset($_POST['fsrep-search-bedrooms'])) { if ($_POST['fsrep-search-bedrooms'] == $i && $_POST['fsrep-search-bedrooms'] != '') { $selectedbed = ' selected'; } }
                    echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.$selectedbed.'>'.$i.'+</option>';
                }
                echo '</select></div>';

        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">Bathrooms:</div>';
        echo '<select name="fsrep-search-bathrooms">';
        echo '<option value="">All</option>';
                $Array = explode(',',$SFields->field_value);
                for($i=0;$i<7.5;$i += 0.5) {
                    $selectedbath = '';
                    if (isset($_POST['fsrep-search-bathrooms'])) { if ($_POST['fsrep-search-bathrooms'] == $i && $_POST['fsrep-search-bathrooms'] != '') { $selectedbath = ' selected'; } }
                    echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.$selectedbath.'>'.$i.'+</option>';
                }
                echo '</select></div>';

        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">Sqft:</div>';
        echo '<select name="fsrep-search-sqft">';
        echo '<option value="">All</option>';
                $Array = explode(',',$SFields->field_value);
                for($i=250;$i<5000;$i += 250) {
                    $selectedsqft = '';
                    if (isset($_POST['fsrep-search-sqft'])) { if ($_POST['fsrep-search-sqft'] == $i && $_POST['fsrep-search-sqft'] != '') { $selectedsqft = ' selected'; } }
                    echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.$selectedsqft.'>'.$i.'+</option>';
                }
                echo '</select></div>';

        if (isset($_POST['fsrep-search-id'])) { $SFieldsValue = $_POST['fsrep-search-id']; }
        echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">Listing#</div><input type="text" name="fsrep-search-id" id="fsrep-search-id" value="'.$SFieldsValue.'" /></div>';


        //echo '<div class="fsrepws-input"><div class="fsrepws-input-title">Listing#</div><input type="text" name="fsrep-search-id" id="fsrep-search-id" value=""></div>';
        echo '<div id="fsrepws-submit"><input type="submit" name="fsrep-search-submit" id="fsrepw-widget-search-submit" value="Search" style="width:127px;font-size:14px" /></div>';




        echo '</form>';
        if ($FSREPconfig['EnableAdvancedSearch'] == 'Yes') {
            echo '<div align="center"><a href="'.get_option('home').'/listings/search/">Advanced Search</a></div>';
        }

        echo $after_widget;
    }
    function fsrep_search_widget_control() {
        $options = get_option('fsrep_search_widget');
        $fsrep_title = htmlspecialchars($options['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
        echo '<div>There are no options for this widget.</div>';
    }
    register_sidebar_widget('FSREP Search Widget', 'fsrep_search_widget');
    register_widget_control('FSREP Search Widget', 'fsrep_search_widget_control');
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'fsrep_search_widget_init');
?>
```

I have been racking my brain on this for over two days trying to figure out what the heck is wrong and I am really hoping it is something easy. You guys would be a life saver if you can help me figure this out.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that `request` is not defined in the scope. Simply changing it over to a connection that is in scope should fix your issue.

Comment: My mind is pretty much mush at this point, so I really appreciate the help. How would I define the scope? I have tried adding var in front, but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd have to have access to the full code to advise you better, and honestly that's a sinkhole I'd really like not to go down tonight. You need access to a already declared XMLHttpRequest within that function. Looking at the code though, I can't really sus out why request.send() is even there. I'm probably missing something, but it may be worth a try temproarily removing it and seeing what happens.